# How do i correct my output from csv file using pandas into python?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, csv

i have 20 columns in the file as excel and i want all the 20 columns to be printed next to each other like a tabular column.

[image]

i have tried all the set _ options for rows columns and width it does not help. How to print it in the manner of a tabular column with 20 fields?

or is there any other module that i can use to print the required data from excel csv file in a neat format for the user?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [tabulate](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/) library

```
from tabulate import tabulate
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(path)
table = tabulate(tabular_data=df, headers=df.columns)
print(table)
```

Note that the console might not be wide enough for proper display, you can write it to a file instead

```
with open('table.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(table)
```

Answer (score -1):

The Python `pandas` library can be used to print the data from 20 or more columns in a tabular format.

you'll need to install the library first. If you haven't installed pip yet, you can do this using it:
`pip install pandas` or `pip3 install pandas`

To read data from an Excel or CSV file and print the columns in a tabular format, use the following sample code:

```
import pandas as pd

# Replace 'your_file.xlsx' with your Excel file or 'your_file.csv' with your CSV file
file_path = 'your_file.xlsx'

# Read data from Excel or CSV file
data = pd.read_excel(file_path)  # For Excel files
# data = pd.read_csv(file_path)  # For CSV files

# Print data in tabular format
print(data)
```

Please let us know if that solves your issue, If you can give us more details that might make sense!
Thank you!

Comment: but then it skips most of the columns and rows with .... and just prints no.of rows and columns below

Comment: All the intro on installing pandas is pointless, and this doesn't answer the question about printing in tabular format, just a regular print and how to read csv (which the OP didn't ask).